# How to get the right image data in base64 format using HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, base64, crop

I'm trying to crop a image using ctx.drawImage() and get the cropped image data using canvas.toDataURL(). However I can't get the right data until I refresh the page few times. I want to know how can I get the cropped image data immediately instead of refresh the page.

```
<script>
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = 'http://localhost:63342/war/img/IMG_20140131_102234.jpg';
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 30;
    canvas.height = 30;

    // Copy the image contents to the canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 715, 715, 0, 0, 30, 30);

    // Get the data-URL formatted image
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    console.log(dataURL);
</script>
```

When I first open the page the data I got are :

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAeCAYAAAA7MK6iAAAAPklEQVRIS+3TsQ0AMAgEMdh/afr0D0XMACBZR9fR9NHdcnhNHjXqmIC4YrTvYtSoYwLiitH6Y3GJKybwX1wD6fcAH1bniBkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

These data are much smaller than the data I got after I refresh the page few times. I'm really confused why this happened and how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wait for your image to be loaded. Use the [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) event.

The reason it works after a few times is because the browser caches it, and makes it load before you run your `toDataURL` code.

For example, your code would look like this:

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = 'http://localhost:63342/war/img/IMG_20140131_102234.jpg';
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 30;
canvas.height = 30;

// Copy the image contents to the canvas
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
imageObj.addEventListener('load', function () {
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 715, 715, 0, 0, 30, 30);

    // Get the data-URL formatted image
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    console.log(dataURL);
});
```