# Error in displaying jpg image data of server side in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax

I am trying to display image form server side image data using ajax call.Server side data is something like this:

```
"ÿØÿàJFIFÿÛC4­¶¸UOHlÊµcBò)3¹_È'I4~&éüÿ§Ú<ã©ã4>'Øù¿ÇÄmËCÈgÚsZ¥ë"
```

In success of Ajax call i assigning this data to the following variable present in java script file.

```
$scope.imgData = <above data>
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-12" > 
  <img src="{{imgData}}" alt="embedded folder icon"></img></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to use base64 image data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images

Comment: Maybe this post will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/q/24787880/1165289

Comment: Seems quite wasteful to use Base64. Why not just get a URL via Ajax and load the image from that URL (can still be dynamically generated on the server)? That would also work better with caching.

Comment: I try to encode that data using jpeg-encode function that you will found in following link: "https://github.com/owencm/javascript-jpeg-encoder/blob/master/jpeg_encoder_basic.js"

Answer (score 1):

Here i got such response that i specified above because response containing an image and i was trying to read it as text. Here i just put my ajax call url in src and i got the image.

Javascript Code: `$scope.imgData = 'secure/image/preview?fileId=1203598625.jpg'`

URL method is: `GET`

HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-12"> 
  <img src="{{imgData}}" alt="embedded folder icon"></img></div>
</div>
```